# How to view the data by id on laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problem here.
I wanna view all data sort by "kelompok".

*kelompok means group

This is the code :

**Controller**

```
public function pengelompokan()
{
    $view = DB::table('tb_siswa')->where('id', $kelompok)->get();
    return view('pengelompokan')
    ->with('view', $view);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('kelompok', 'belajarController@kelompok');
```

Comment: Its seems your routes need to be `Route::get('/{kelompok}', 'belajarController@pengelompokan');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` collection method:

```
$view = DB::table('tb_siswa')
    ->where('id', $kelompok)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('kelompok');
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, you could do this:

```
Route::get('kelompok/{groupId}', 'belajarController@kelompok');


public function pengelompokan($kelompok)
{
    $view = DB::table('tb_siswa')
      ->where('id', $kelompok)
      ->get()
      ->groupBy('kelompok');

    return view('pengelompokan', compact('view'));
}
```

Comment: I had a problem like this
Undefined variable: kelompok

Comment: @IqbalNurkholik how you are hitting your route? and what you expect `kelompok` to be?

Comment: @IqbalNurkholik How are you reaching this controller method? From the wording of your original question, it sounds like you already at the id stored in $kelompok

Comment: Problem Solved, Thank's :D

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to resolve this

```
public function pengelompokan()
{
    $view = DB::table('tb_siswa')->where('id', $kelompok)
            ->groupBy('kelompok')->get();
    return view('pengelompokan')->with('view');
}
```

You can access `groupBy` data using a variable `$view` on blade as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Routes but you can apply it on your Controller@show

```
Route::get('tutorial/{id}', function($id){
$tutorial = Tutorial::findOrFail($id);
return view('tutorial.show')->with('tutorial', $tutorial);})->name('show-tutorial');
```

and Also Check on your show.blade.php